# Return student_ids where at least one of each category

Tags: sql, oracle

Say we have three tables students, assignments, and subjects. I want to return all student_ids where that student has completed at least one assignment in each subject that a student named first_name = 'place' and last_name = 'holder' has.

Student table:

```
Student_id | first_name | last_name
------------------------------------
     1     |   place    | holder
     2     |            |           
     3     |            |
```

Subjects:

```
subject_id | name
-----------------
     1     | Math
     2     | English
     3     | Science
```

Assignments:

```
student_id | subject_id
-----------------------
     1     |    1
     1     |    2
     1     |    3
     2     |    1
     2     |    2
     2     |    3
     3     |    1
     3     |    2
```

So, in this case I would want my query results to be:

```
student_id
----------
     1
     2
```

I've tried a number of different methods like using set operations and stuff like that but none of them seem to get exactly the right results. I keep getting all the students who have completed at least one assignment in ANY subject that student 'place holder' has completed an assignment in.

Comment: Have a look at group by clause, and having clause .. for a tip you can use having count(*) >= 1

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Join to get the desired result. That is given that there is only one assignment per subject:

```
SELECT students.student_id FROM students
INNER JOIN assignments on assignments.student_id = students.student_id
GROUP BY students.student_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM subjects)
```

Answer (score 0):

Joining two tables `Subjects` and `Assignments` is enough. You need to reach the count of subjects for the desired students.

```
with Subjects( subject_id, name) as
(
 select 1,'Math'    from dual union all
 select 2,'English' from dual union all
 select 3,'Science' from dual
),   
     Assignments( student_id, subject_id) as
(     
 select 1,1 from dual union all
 select 1,2 from dual union all 
 select 1,3 from dual union all
 select 2,1 from dual union all
 select 2,2 from dual union all
 select 2,3 from dual union all
 select 3,1 from dual union all
 select 3,2 from dual
)
select student_id
  from ( select count(distinct subject_id) as subject_id from Subjects ) s
  join Assignments a on a.subject_id = s.subject_id 

student_id
----------
1
2
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the placeholder name in the other answers as a query condition, which I think is part of what is being asked for. I will break this down into preliminary queries with comments so you can follow how the final solution is built:

```
--this will get a 'standard' list of subjects 
--(with at least one completed assignment by the 'standard' student)
--to which all students will be compared
select distinct subject_id
from assignments a
inner join students s
on s.student_id = a.student_id
where s.first_name = 'place'
and s.last_name = 'holder';


--cross join the students and the list above 
--we will outer join this to the assigments table later
select students.student_id as std_student, standard_subjects.subject_id as std_subj
from students, 
(select distinct subject_id
from assignments a
inner join students s
on s.student_id = a.student_id
where s.first_name = 'place'
and s.last_name = 'holder') standard_subjects;


--outer join this to a set of completions 
--to compare actual completions to 
--the standard set by the 'placeholder' student
with completions as (select student_id, subject_id 
from assignments
group by student_id, subject_id
) 
select std_student, std_subj, student_id
from (select students.student_id as std_student, standard_subjects.subject_id as std_subj
from students, 
(select distinct subject_id
from assignments a
inner join students s
on s.student_id = a.student_id
where s.first_name = 'place'
and s.last_name = 'holder') standard_subjects) standard
left join completions
on standard.std_student = completions.student_id
and standard.std_subj = completions.subject_id;


--sum up the completions and select only the students
--having a completion in each 'standard' subject
select std_student as result 
from (
with completions as (select student_id, subject_id 
from assignments
group by student_id, subject_id
) 
select std_student, std_subj, student_id
from (select students.student_id as std_student, standard_subjects.subject_id as std_subj
from students, 
(select distinct subject_id
from assignments a
inner join students s
on s.student_id = a.student_id
where s.first_name = 'place'
and s.last_name = 'holder') standard_subjects) standard
left join completions
on standard.std_student = completions.student_id
and standard.std_subj = completions.subject_id) comparison
having count(student_id) = count(std_subj)
group by std_student;
```